# Docker: Is A Repository, ImageID A Container?

Tags: centos, docker

I have installed docker on a VM and downloaded two repositories/images `vyos` and `vyos-documentaiton`.  Now I want to "run/"install" them to start configuring vyos.

I ran `docker start image ID`, `docker start repositoryName`
but got `No such container` for both commands. I was expecting to see some forward movement in the process. But clearly I am looking at this inaccurately.

So do I need to make a container now? I figured the VM I am on is the container.  I can see [here](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container)

> A container is a standard unit of software that packages up code and all its dependencies so the application runs quickly and reliably from one computing environment to another. A Docker container image is a lightweight, standalone, executable package of software that includes everything needed to run an application: code, runtime, system tools, system libraries and settings.

So it appears to me the repositories/image IDs and VM make up a containers.
I am simply confused with the terminology at this point.  I prefer K.I.S.S. principle.
[image]

Comment: Right below the quoted passage: "Container images become containers at runtime" ... so you need to [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) the image to make a container.

Comment: I see, thanks. Looks like the first image vyos manual made movement, second one not so much. Says "no command specified", yet I though 'run' was the command? There must be flags I am unaware of.